# Сказуемое в безличном: Некогда раздумывать

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые

Чувствую себя безумно глупо, но прошу помощи. Не могу определить члены предложения в предложении "Некогда раздумывать". Некогда раздумывать - сказуемое? Или некогда - обстоятельство? Или некогда - сказуемое, а раздумывать - дополнение?..

Или вот: "Нельзя терять ни минуты". Нельзя терять - сказуемое? Или нет?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это сказуемые: ***нельзя терять (ни минуты), некогда раздумывать***. *Нельзя, некогда* - предикативные наречия (или слова категории состояния).

***Предикативные наречия*** представлены двумя группами.

[Предикативные наречия](https://studfiles.net/preview/407670/page:54/): В одной группе объединяются неизменяемые слова (их немного), которые всегда употребляются предикативно: жаль, нельзя, можно, надо, стыдно, совестно, тошно, замужем, наготове, впору (в признаковом значении: туфли впору). Одни из них ***употребляются в предложениях с инфинитивом в роли главного члена*** (*нельзя проехать, можно уйти, надо собираться*), другие, кроме этого, могут быть главным членом безличного предложения (ему совестно, детям стыдно за свои поступки. мне тошно от всего случившегося), третьи бывают сказуемьм в двусоставном предложении (женщина замужем, пушки наготове, туфли впору).